# jsp plus image and text combination

Tags: jsp

How to show **image** and **text** on same jsp page

Answer (score 1):

Just use the HTML `<img>` element to display an image in the webpage. The text can just be placed anywhere you want the usual HTML way. Assuming that you've an image `image.gif` which sits in the same folder as the JSP file, here's how the HTML should look like.

```
<p><img src="image.gif"><br/>some text</p>
```

This is not a JSP problem per se since it just provides a template to write HTML in which in turn is to be interpreted by the webbrowser.

Answer (score -1):

using div tag

```
<DIV class='paragraph'>
<a href="image"<IMG alt=title src="image" width=300 class='imageRight'></a>
<SPAN class='portion'>(A)</SPAN>
Paragraph
</DIV>
```

or

```
<img src="img.gif" align="left">Put all your text here
```